# Show specific number of array objects (React)

Tags: javascript, json, loops, reactjs

I am trying to loop through JSON data and only show the first "4" results, but through all of my searching most of the answers I have seen use forEach() or map() which loops through all of the data. I have tried using for(), but it results in nothing displaying on the page. If anyone can help or direct me to an answer I haven't been able to find that would be great!

```
{this.state.products.map(function(product) {
    return(
        <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3" key={product.productId}>
            <img src={product.productImage1} Image1 alt="Logo"/>
            <h3>{product.productTitle}</h3>
            <p>{product.productDesc}<a href="/">Learn More</a></p>
        </div>
    );
})}
```

Comment: May be you should use index parameter in map method- like ( if index < 4 ...)

Comment: Do you have a link that references map method referencing index?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26371083/javascript-arraymap-index-argument

Comment: Thanks :) will look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`slice`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp) method before `map`.

```
{this.state.products.slice(0, 4).map(...)}
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed.